# Каким образом сделать вывод текста после нажатия кнопки в dearpygui?

Tags: python, dearpygui

Есть вот такой код, каким образом мне сделать вывод текста из main_txt после нажатия кнопки btn

```
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

dpg.create_context()
dpg.create_viewport(title='Custom Title', width=800, height=300)

with dpg.window(label='Main Window'):
    main_txt = dpg.add_input_text()
    btn = dpg.add_button(label='Start', tag=99)

dpg.setup_dearpygui()
dpg.show_viewport()
dpg.start_dearpygui()
dpg.destroy_context()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь аргументом `callback` при создании кнопки.

Короткий пример без инициализации dearpygui:

```
def btn_pressed(sender, app_data, user_data):
    print(sender, app_data, user_data)

dearpygui.add_button(tag="button", label="I print all my data", user_data="your args for callback", callback=btn_pressed)
```

Подробнее можете посмотреть в документации [по созданию кнопок](https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/dearpygui.html#dearpygui.dearpygui.add_button) и [по item callback](https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/item-callbacks.html).

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).